# Image on popup window in google maps v3 api?

Tags: image, google-maps, popup, google-maps-markers

How I can put an image on a popup window when I click on a marker (bondi beach) in google maps v3 ? :

Here the code :

```js
var locations = [
// Here I would put the Image ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.713251, 7.833252),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
});

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
     map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
     return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
   })(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```html
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
```

script :

```js
var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 'http://www.destination360.com/australia-south-pacific/australia/images/s/australia-bondi-beach.jpg'],
    /*
    add more locations here on the form :
    [ name, lat, long, img ]
    [ name, lat, long, img ]
    ..
    */
];

function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                var content=locations[i][0]+'<br><img src="'+locations[i][3]+'" style="width:300px;">';
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsa/)

**result** :

[image]

Comment: Okay - dont know why you cant see the image, tested here in Chrome / FireFox, here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsa/, just set width/height on the image as above. The max width of infowindow is the width of your map.

Comment: I see the Image but it show alsow another broken image and i nont konw why.. 
look here: www.designerstudio.ch/bug.jpg
<br>
....here the code:   var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach <br>beispieltext: 1000 jahre<br><img src="test.jpg">', -33.890542, 151.274856, ],
  
];

Comment: This is because in the example I assume the image is the last string in the array `[name, lat, long, img]` - you have `[mixedhtml, lat, long]` - simply change `var content=locations[i][0]+'<br><img src="'+locations[i][3]+'" style="width:300px;">';` to `var content=locations[i][0];`

Comment: What's the parameter for adding Get Directions?